# Como setar um valor igual para uma propriedade de um objeto em todos os objetos de uma lista?

Tags: javascript

Como setar um valor para uma propriedade em todos os índices da lista sem fazer um loop?

objeto:

```
var objeto = {
  nome: "",
  ativo: false
}
```

lista:

```
[{"nome": "Carlos","ativo":false},{"nome": "Joao","ativo":false}]
```

Neste exemplo, todos as pessoas deveriam ter a propriedade ativo alterada para true.

O jeito que resolve:

```
    for (var i in lista) {
         lista[i].ativo = true;        
    }
```

Tem algum modo de evitar esse loop, fazer essa alteração de uma vez só? pois na aplicação real o objeto é mais complexo e tem muitos registros, deixando este método lento.

Comment: Sem fazer um _loop_ não deve dar, talvez seja possível otimizar este laço pra ficar mais rápido. Não faz muito sentido conseguir acessar todos os itens de uma lista sem ter que passar por todos eles.

Comment: Se voce não fizer um *loop*, alguém irá estar fazendo por trás, caso exista alguma biblioteca que faça isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando a entrada:

```
let data = [
    {"nome": "Carlos","ativo": false},
    {"nome": "Joao","ativo": false}
];
```

No padrão ES6, você pode utilizar `Object.assign` para mesclar dois objetos. Veja:

```js
// Dados de entrada:
let data = [
    {"nome": "Carlos", "ativo": false},
    {"nome": "Joao", "ativo": false}
];

// Altera todos os objetos da lista:
data = data.map(obj => Object.assign(obj, {"ativo": true}));

// Exibe o resultado:
console.log(data);
```

Caso não queira utilizar tal método, pode fazer a alteração na mão:

```js
// Dados de entrada:
let data = [
    {"nome": "Carlos", "ativo": false},
    {"nome": "Joao", "ativo": false}
];

// Altera todos os objetos da lista:
data = data.map(obj => {
  obj.ativo = true;
  return obj;
});

// Exibe o resultado:
console.log(data);
```

Um [*benchmark*](http://jsben.ch/#/CmJGo) simples mostra que fazer o `for` diretamente é mais rápido, seguido da segunda solução aqui presente e, por fim, a solução que utiliza o método `assign`. Ou seja, você economiza alguns caracteres, mas perde em eficiência. Nesse caso, como é simples, não há porque não utilizar o próprio `for`.

Comment: Mas o map não estará fazendo um loop também?

Comment: @alan de certa forma, sim. Só evita de você ter que escrevê-lo. Algumas linguagens conseguem otimizar a execução do `map`. Não sei dizer se é o caso do JavaScript.